# Change value of currently iterated element in list

Tags: python

problem:
when you use construction

```
for a in _list_:
    print a
```

it prints every item in array. But you can't alter array. Is it possible to alter value of array (something like a=123, but that ain't working)
I know it's possible (for example in while loop), but I want to do it this way (more elegant)

In PHP it would be like

```
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    $value = 123;
}
```

(because of `&` sign, is passed as reference)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
for idx, a in enumerate(foo):
    foo[idx] = a + 42
```

Note though, that if you're doing this, you probably should look into list comprehensions (or `map`), unless you really want to mutate in place (just don't insert or remove items from iterated-on list).

The same loop written as a list comprehension looks like:

```
foo = [a + 42 for a in foo]
```

Answer (score 8):

Because python iterators are just a "label" to a object in memory, setting it will make it just point to something else.

If the iterator is a mutable object (list, set, dict etc) you can modify it and see the result in the same object.

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
>>> for i in a:
...    i.append(10)
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3, 10], [4, 5, 6, 10]]
```

If you want to set each value to, say, 123 you can either use the list index and access it or use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a = [123 for i in a]
>>> a
[123, 123, 123, 123, 123]
```

But you'll be creating another list and binding it to the same name.

Answer (score 1):

```
for a in _list_:
  _list_[_list_.index(a)]=123
```

Comment: this is terribly inefficient :(