# How to convert a single item in a list to .lower()

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, if-statement

How do I convert single item in a list by using for loop?
I want program to recognize plane not being in lowercase and making it lowercase.

```
vehicles = ['car', 'bicycle', 'Plane',]

for vehicle in vehicles:
    if vehicle == vehicle.lower():
        print(f"{vehicle.title()} is in lowercase")
    else:
        print(f"Vehicle is not in lowercase: {vehicle}")
```

I tried with:

```
if vehicle in vehicles != vehicle.lower():
    vehicle = vehicle.lower()

print(vehicles)
```

But when I print list again, it still shows plane with first capital letter.

Edit: Sorry for some confusion, I added "print(f"{vehicle.title()} is in lowercase")" just for esthetics. What I want, is to make program recognize string not being in lowercase and then modify that string in a list, then when list in being printed again, it shows "Plane" in list as "plane".

Comment: Your first bit of code should work just fine. Your second doesn't make sense.

Comment: it shows the first capital letter because you are calling `.title()` just remove the calling to `.title()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change value of currently iterated element in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528848/change-value-of-currently-iterated-element-in-list)

Answer (score 1):

Your first bit of code correctly detects whether a string is not lowercased, but you print the non-lowercased version (using `vehicle.title()`). You don't actually *need* to detect whether it's lowercase or not. Just lowercase them all --- it's cheap enough.

```
vehicles = [vehicle.lower() for vehicle in vehicles]
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply to make everything lowercase in that case you could use list comprehension:

```
vehicles_lower = [v.lower() for v in vehicles]
print(vehicles_lower)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a duplicate of
[Change value of currently iterated element in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528848/change-value-of-currently-iterated-element-in-list)

You have to change your for loop like this if you want to change the list:

```
a_list = ["a", "b", "c"]

for i in range(len(a_list)):
    a_list[i] = a_list[i] + a_list[i]

print(a_list)
```

In his answer, @erip provided yet another syntax to do it by assigning the result back to the list.