# how to supress very small scientific notations to zero?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, loops

In sub-list of `b` the numbers are very close to zero ,  i wanted to make it equal to zeros if, they are >-1e-05.

is there is any better method ?

```
b = [[0.0, -2.220446049250313e-16, -8.881784197001252e-16, -6.661338147750939e-16, 0.0],
     [0.0, -0.1875000, -0.1250000, -0.0625000, 0.0], 
     [0.0, -0.125000, -0.25000, -0.1250, 0.0], 
     [0.0, -0.06250, -0.1250, -0.18750, 0.0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

for i in b:
    for j in i:
        if j > -1e-05:
            j = 0
        else:
            j = j
```

Comment: `[[0 if j>-1e-05 else j for j in i] for i in b]`

Comment: Thank you sir, a little idiotic doubt i have.... sir in the above written code (by me) , if i `print( b)` ,  it is printing the same list , what should i do to incorporate the `if `  `else` condition in b? ... if i want to use the same code written by me

Comment: You need to assign the value back to `b`, You may want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528848/change-value-of-currently-iterated-element-in-list

Comment: Is your aim only to pretty print the array?

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong  No sir, my aim is to get the updated `B list`, by converging very very small values to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you can use `numpy` and `np.where`. First transform your list into an array:

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array(b)
```

Then use `np.where` to modify your array. The first argument is your condition, the second is the value you want your array to have when the condition is satisfied and the the third is the value you want your array to have when the condition is not satisfied:

```
>>> np.where(b>-10**(-5), 0, b)
array([[ 0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ],
       [ 0.    , -0.1875, -0.125 , -0.0625,  0.    ],
       [ 0.    , -0.125 , -0.25  , -0.125 ,  0.    ],
       [ 0.    , -0.0625, -0.125 , -0.1875,  0.    ],
       [ 0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ]])
```